# Trouble using cin to pass 2 values by reference in a function

Tags: c++, function, reference, cin

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void scan_data(char&, float&);
void do_next_op(char, float, float&);

int main()
{
    float accumulator; //value on the left of the equation
    float operand; //value on the right
    char op = ' ';

    while(op != 'q')
    {
        scan_data(op, operand); //retrieve the operator and operand from the file
        do_next_op(op, operand, accumulator);
        if (op != 'q')
        {
            cout << "Result so far is " << setprecision(1) << fixed << accumulator;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}

void scan_data(char& op, float& operand)
{
    cin >> op >> operand;
}

void do_next_op(char op, float operand, float& accumulator)
{
    if (op == '+')
    {
        accumulator = accumulator + operand;

    }
    else if (op == '-')
    {
        accumulator = accumulator - operand;
    }
    else if (op == '*')
    {
        accumulator = accumulator * operand;
    }
    else if (op == '/')
    {
        if (operand != 0)
        {
            accumulator = accumulator / operand;
            cout << "Result so far is " << fixed << setprecision(1) << accumulator << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Error: Division by zero";
        }
    }
    else if (op == '^')
    {
        accumulator = pow(accumulator, operand);
    }
    else if (op == 'q')
    {
        cout << "Final result is " << accumulator << ".";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error: invalid operator" << endl;
    }
}
```

I am unable to run this although xcode is not telling me there is anything wrong with the syntax. Can you guys point me in the right direction on how to get it running?

Comment: Put the relevant code in the question, not an offsite link, because if the link dies your question is no longer useful to others. Thanks.

Comment: And tell us what the problem is. An error message or incorrect output.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with the syntax as I was able to run it on VS2013.  You need to initialize accumulator (float accumulator(0)) to get any meaningful calculations.

You should also add something to prompt the users to enter the op and operand in your scan_data function.

Lastly you should test for q after the user enters it and not force them to enter 'q' then another number, depending what your use for the program is.

```
void scan_data(char& op, float& operand)
{
    cin >> op;
    if(op == 'q')
        return;

    cin >> operand;
}
```